# How could I pick out specific range of data from an array in C?

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, date-range

I am using a dual channel DAQ with data streaming mode.

The output data will become an array, however, I just want a specific range of the data from it and do the calculation and analysis, otherwise too much data points will retard the system and cause the FIFO overflow.

Does `C` code have a similar function like Matlab `array(6000:7000)`?

Here is my code to get the channel 1 and channel 2 data and I want to select a specific range of data from the `ch1Buffer[i]` and `ch2Buffer[i]`

```
uInt32 i, n;
uInt8* pu8Buffer = NULL;
int16* pi16Buffer = NULL;
int64 i64Sum = 0;
float max1 = 0;
float max2 = 0;
double Corrected = 0;
double AUC = 0;
int16* ch1Buffer = NULL;
int16* ch2Buffer = NULL;
double SumBufferData( void* pBuffer, uInt32 u32Size, uInt32 u32SampleBits )
{
    // In this routine we sum up all the samples in the buffer. This function 
    // should be replaced with the user's analysys function
    if ( 8 == u32SampleBits )
    {
        pu8Buffer = (uInt8 *)pBuffer;
        for (i = 0; i < u32Size; i++)
        {
            i64Sum += pu8Buffer[i];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        pi16Buffer = (int16 *)pBuffer;
        fftw_complex(hilbertedch2[N]);

        ch1Buffer       = (int16*)calloc(u32Size/2, sizeof(int16));
        ch2Buffer       = (int16*)calloc(u32Size/2, sizeof(int16));

        // Divide ch1 and ch2 data from pi16Buffer
        for (i = 0; i < u32Size/2; i++)
        {
            ch1Buffer[i] += pi16Buffer[i*2];
            ch2Buffer[i] += pi16Buffer[i*2 + 1];
        }
        // Here hilbert on the whole ch2
        hilbert(ch2Buffer, hilbertedch2);

        //Find max value in each segs of ch1 and ch2
        for (i = 0; i < u32Size/2; i++)
        {
            if (ch1Buffer[i] > max1)
                max1 = ch1Buffer[i];

            if (abs(hilbertedch2[i][IMAG])> max2)
                max2 = abs(hilbertedch2[i][IMAG]);
        }
        Corrected = (max2 / max1); // Calculate the signal correction
    }
    free(ch1Buffer);
    free(ch2Buffer);
    return Corrected;
}
```

Comment: you can use [memcpy](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html) where you can mention your source address as start address from where you want to copy the data and instead of range, you can mention the number of bytes need to be copied from that start address and  you need to give destination address to store this data. and have a look at the man page to see the limitations(source & destination should not overlap)

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like for Linux. I am using C is that suitable?

Comment: What about `for(i = 6000; i < 7000; i++) { do_whatever_with array[i] }`?

Comment: Its a `C` function

Comment: @Davide That looks the simplest and straightforward one, I will try it and see thanks!

Comment: You are very welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does C code have a similar function like Matlab array(6000:7000)?

Yes, it's called `memcpy`. But being C, it is harder to use and it is unaware of the structure and size of your data.

```
int source_array[500]; 
// assume array gets filled somehow

int dest_array[50];
// dest_array = source_array[100:150] (not C code)
memcpy(dest_array, &source_array[100], 50*sizeof(source_array[0]);
```

And as `memcpy`is highly optimized, it beats a for loop every time.

Comment: Hi, if I understand clearly, I will build a new array called `ch2newBuffer` to get the value which I'm interested the 6000 to 7000 range from `ch2Buffer` and with the `memcpy` writing format it will become `memcpy(ch2newBuffer, &ch2Buffer[6000], 1000*sizeof(ch2Buffer[0]))` am I right?

Comment: @kevin, yes. Unless I completely misunderstand what the MatLab syntax does.

Comment: Thanks! Btw, I got a problem to print out the answer. I wrote: `for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
 {
  printf("a[%d] = %f\n", i, *ch2newBuffer);
  ch2newBuffer++;` which I only pick out two values from `ch2Buffer` want to check if they are what I want. How could I modify this print out function?

Comment: `Exception thrown at 0x00007FFF4C2A1399 (vcruntime140d.dll) in Examplefordebug.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000000.`

Comment: The problem is solved, but I will still give you the credit, thanks!